how stop water pass through a cup when i throw ice cubes in it?

I want to create an animation of ice cubes being thrown into a cup, but the water molecules pass through the walls of the cup.

Maybe try thickening your glass obstacle ? You can use another version of your glass object only for physics and not rendered, to achieve satisfactory thickness.
